# How do I repair plantation shutters

Tags: shutters

The staple or brad that connects the control bar to several of the shutters have come off.  Some of them are completely lost.  How do I repair this?

Answer (score 5):

I used to own and run a Blind business.  Living in Florida, a majority of our volume were shutters.  I would suggest getting a staple that is slightly longer than the one that came out  and then pushing the new one in.

I would protect the lever with a towel and then use a wide wrench, like a plumbers wrench, to squeeze the staple in.  Another option which would probably be easier would be to use the same size staple that fell out and use a two-part epoxy to set them in the holes.  You may have to get a small syringe to inject the mix into the tiny holes before inserting the staple.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple, I'll give that a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Plastic syringes are available for these types of uses.  My wife works at a vet, so these are at my disposal.  If you use one with a metal needle, be VARY careful.  Injecting yourself with epoxy would be dangerous.

Comment: I would add that since I use epoxy to hold the crown staple into the control arm or blade I pre drill two tiny holes to make insertion easier.

Comment: I just started using gel Cyanoacrylate cements; pretty useful for something like this.